# Why does typing "e! Kee" into a URL do a ebay search for the word "kee"?

Tags: firefox, youtube

Seems to flash to a search engine before that as-well. Im thinking that "e!" tells the browser to go to ebay or something.

I stumbled on this issue while doing the normal youtube browsing that normal people do and saw a user with no name or profile pic.
You can see it here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4i1Xsamln2U but you need to "sort by" "newest first" in the comments section then scroll down to the bottom.
[image]

Somewhere in my search for the username in the inspect element page, I stumbled upon the term "e! Kee". A URL search leads me to ebay and it even kicks me off my gifcam software somehow. Its either I have a virus and someone is messing with me or im missing some eepic part about that phrase/shortcut.
Also, does anyone know how to get a youtube profile without a username like in the example I gave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e!` is a [DuckDuckGo Bang](https://duckduckgo.com/bang). Bangs are essentially shortcuts to search on other sites, `e` here redirecting to Ebay but there's many others. So for example you could do `!e computer` and you'd get Ebay results for "computer" or `!w computer` and get Wikipedia results.